# Typescript Project References with Webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have been working on trying to speed up my webpack build of a Typescript project.   I cant seem to find any information of whether or not webpack respects Typescript project references.  I added a tsconfig to folder and build it independent of the rest of the project and the outDir was created and .js and .map files were output. However when I build with webpack  .js/.map files were generated and placed in the outDir.

Is this supposed to work?  Can't seem to find and info on it.

Answer (score 3):

There is support for project references in Webpack via [ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#projectreferences), which may work for you.

Beware that there is [more work being done](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/pull/1028) toward ts-loader 7.0.0, so your mileage may vary.